# How to generate diagram from OpenAI create image that has English words?

Tags: node.js, openai-api

By using nodejs openai npm package, I am generating images also by adding string ' can you give a diagram?" at the end I am getting diagram but every diagram has some meaningless words anyone can tell me why?

```
const { Configuration, OpenAIApi } = require("openai");
    
        const configuration = new Configuration({
          apiKey: apiKey,
        });
        const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);
        try {
          const response = await openai.createImage({
            prompt:
              query +
              " , can you give a diagram? ",
            n: 2,
            size: "256x256",
          });
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

for prompt, you show that the input is query and then can you give me a diagram

it would be better if you can explain it explicitly, maybe reorder the sentence, so it would be totally clear what you want to create, and for sure the clearer the better.

after all, it is based on LLM, so it depends on how you specify your input.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).